# Find keys of dictionary that sum to 6

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm having trouble accessing multiple values in a dictionary. Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
{'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4, '6': 5}
```

I want to find two keys that sum to 6 and display their values. Here, the keys 4 and 2 add to 6, so the 2 values are 3 and 1.

Where do I start? This is the code I have so far:

```
for key in dico:
        if sum(key + key) == 6:
                print(f"Numbers @ {key:dico} have a sum of 6")
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for extra loops (or itertools), they will only slow your program down. You already know what the other index needs to be (because you can subtract the index from 6), so just check if that index exists:

```
dct = {'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4, '6': 5}

for i, key in enumerate(dct):
    if i + 2 > len(dct)/2:
        break
    
    matchIndex = str(6 - int(key))
    if dct.get(matchIndex) is not None:
        print(f'Keys {key} and {matchIndex} have values {dct[key]} and {dct[matchIndex]}')
```

This approach has a O(n/2) time complexity, while the other answer has O(n^2) time complexity.

When I tested this approach with `timeit`, it took 1.72 seconds to run this answer one million times, but the itertools answer took 5.83 secondss.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Yes, I have updated my answer. Although in this case, this approach is faster.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I've updated my answer to include exact times I got with `timeit`. They show this approach is the fastest.

Comment: It will show values two times in each case,

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational It prints both the keys and the values. If you want, you can print only the keys. It just depends on the `print()` call

Comment: No two times means, it will show pair like this: (1, 5) and also (5,1) which does not make sense as both are same. You can reduce this time as well.

Comment: Also it will be showing 3 as the answer which should not be the case, because 3 is appearing one time.

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational I've fixed my answer to only loop through half of the keys. Thanks for the good catch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249356/discussion-between-assume-irrational-is-rational-and-michael-m).

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational I've updated my answer to fix the problem you pointed out. Now it'll only loop through half of the keys

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compare each of the dictionary keys with the rest of the other keys. You can use `itertools` for this.

As you mention you would like to print the `value` of each of the keys you have in your dictionary, it would be something like this:

```
import itertools

dico = {'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4, '6': 5}

for a, b in itertools.combinations(dico.keys(), 2):
    if int(a) + int(b) == 6:
        print(f"{dico[a]} - {dico[b]}")
```

Comment: This will be very time taking if done on lot of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops for that.

Also, have in mind that there is more than one answer to that problem

```
a = {'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4, '6': 5}

results = list()

for key_1 in a.keys():
  for key_2 in a.keys():
    if key_1 != key_2:
      if a[key_1] + a[key_2] == 6:
        if a[key_1] < a[key_2]:
          results.append((key_1, key_2))

print(results)
```